# Iterating over multiple files and replacing a single line - why doesn't it work?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to use the `fileinput` module to iterate over a bunch of files and replace a single line in them. This is how my code looks:

```
def main():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('target/generated-sources'):
        for line in fileinput.input([os.path.join(root, file) for file in files if file.endsWith('.java')], inplace=True):
            match = re.search(r'@Table\(name = "(.*)"\)', line)
            output = "".join(['@Table(name = "', PREFIX, match.group(1)[MAX_TABLENAME_LEN - len(PREFIX)], '")', '\n']) if match else line
            print output,
```

The problem I face is that I get no error, and the script somehow seems to block. I'm using Python 2.5.2.

Comment: Do you also get no output? Does it only block in some GUI interpreter or also if run straight from the command line? What happens if you run it against just a single `.java` file? Show us a sample of the files you're matching against so we can run the program ourselves.

Comment: @Andrew it's not two for loops, it's a list comprehension as an argument to a function, and a for loop? Nothing wrong with that, I do it all the time.

Comment: @agf, yes, I get no output when run from the commandline, and it seems to run forever.

Comment: @agf oops, you're right of course. Too early...

Comment: @Oliver and how does it work if run on just one `.java` file instead of `fileinput`?

Comment: `.endsWith` should be `.endswith`

Comment: @agf It runs without problems.

Comment: And what happens if you run it without `inplace = True`? Does it spew out the file contents? You won't see any output with `inplace` set to `True` because it's redirecting `stdout` to the file...

Comment: You might want to `import sys` and then add a line `print >> sys.sterr 'now in dir', root` just inside the outer for loop so you can at least see when you change directories.

Comment: Also try moving the list comprehension to it's own line and generally adding more `print`s so you know what line it's blocking on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list comprehension is returning empty lists when a root does not contain `.java` files. When your script passes an empty list to  `fileinput.input()`, it reverts to the default expecting input from stdin. Since there is nothing coming in from stdin, your script blocks.

Try this instead:

```
def main():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('target/generated-sources'):
        java_files = [os.path.join(root, file) for file in files if file.endsWith('.java')]
        if not java_files:  # go to next iteration if list is empty
            continue
        for line in fileinput.input(java_files, inplace=True):
            match = re.search(r'@Table\(name = "(.*)"\)', line)
            output = "".join(['@Table(name = "', PREFIX, match.group(1)[MAX_TABLENAME_LEN - len(PREFIX)], '")', '\n']) if match else line
            print output,
```

Alternatively, split up the logic of the file discovery. The following creates a generator which produces a list of files which you can then use as an input to `fileinput`.

```
import os, fnmatch, fileinput

def find_files(directory, pattern):
    "Generator that returns files  within direction with name matching pattern"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
            yield filename

for line in fileinput.input(find_files("target/generated-sources", "*.java")):
    match = re.search(r'@Table\(name = "(.*)"\)', line)
    output = "".join(['@Table(name = "', PREFIX, match.group(1)[MAX_TABLENAME_LEN - len(PREFIX)], '")', '\n']) if match else line
    print output,
```

Comment: That's right! By default fileinput attaches to sys.stdin if filelist is empty!

Comment: What does `if not java_files: continue` do?

Comment: That means that if `java_files` is empty, skip the rest of the loop and continue with the next iteration.

Comment: @Shawn Argh, yeah, of course. Thx, that was exactely my problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where the interpreter blocks, you can send signal SIGINT to the process. At least on unix like operating systems.

```
kill -sigint PID
```

Try to add some print or logging- lines, to see where your code hangs. Maybe fileinput works well, and the app blocks after that.

Some time ago I wrote a tool to do search+replace in several files:
http://www.thomas-guettler.de/scripts/reprec.py.txt